# How to use interface in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I know the concept of "Interfaces" but I've hard time to understand how to use them in android development.

Let's say I created an interface to decide if to show progress bar or not -

```
interface ProgressBarInterface {
    fun showProgressBar()
    fun hideProgressBar()
}
```

And I implement this inside BaseActivity/MainActivity in single Activity app:

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ProgressBarInterface {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    override fun showProgressBar() {

    }

    override fun hideProgressBar() {

    }
}
```

And inside my other activity I've a button, that when I click on it, I want to trigger `showProgressBar` in the base activity:

```
  button.setOnClickListener { 
            //Show progress bar
        }
```

How can I interact with the interface to trigger the function inside base activity?

Comment: You have already added the implementation of the `showProgressBar()` in your `BaseActivity`. But it's empty. You can write your `BaseActivity` specific code there. If that is not what you mean, please clarify why you are using an interface here. Is there a place where you accept any Activity that implements your interface?

Comment: @lucidbrot I know I need to write code in interface functiond inside base activity, My question was how can I call show/hide progress bar inside the activities that extends Base activity, in order to "Activate" the functions inside base activity

Comment: Do you know how you would do it without an interface? (If not, I suggest you read up on that first). I may be misunderstanding you, but I think you want to create multiple different Activity classes that all implement your interface so that you could call `showProgressBar()` on any of them, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already are implementing the interface in your BaseActivity, you can then just add what you need to do inside the interface methods, and then call them up in any point in your activity, if what you are looking for is to extend this BaseActiviy into more activities you will need to make this BaseActivity abstract then you can extend in each activity this BaseClass and just use the interface methods

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() , ProgressBarInterface {
    private val TAG = "MainActivity"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    override fun showProgressBar() {
       progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun hideProgressBar() {
       progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

and then in your Activities you can extend from BaseActivity() and just use your interface methods as you have defined in that BaseActivity() to prevent coding them again, you can do

```
class FirstActivity : BaseActivity() {
 
...

button.setOnClickListener {
  showProgressBar()
}
```

An easier way to show and hide the views? Use extension functions

```
fun View.show() {
    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun View.hide() {
    this.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

you can define that extensions in any class, for example `ViewUtils.kt` and then just call

```
 button.setOnClickListener {
      progressBar.show()
    }
```

or

```
button.setOnClickListener {
          progressBar.hide()
        }
```

Comment: Is `abstract` actually required? Why (or why do you recommend it)? I have a hunch, but I think it would be great if you were explicit about it :) Also, shouldn't it be `showProgressBar()` in the last code sample?

Comment: Typo on the last example, thanks :) . I have used abstract classes because if you have more than one activities that does the same thing over and over again in your code, you can extend from a BaseActivity (thats why the abstract is needed) and then just use the methods that are already defined inside of it, its easier if you do an extension function for the progressBar that puts its visibility to gone or visible

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a question about your last part - For my understanding, the extension function implemetiton require me to add progress bar view to every layout, no? In base activity you need only one progress bar view

Comment: the extension function is just a way to not write progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE each time you want to show your progressBar, instead, now, is an extension of the View class, and now every view you want to hide or show you can use hide() or show() to it. As your question, yes, the extension function does not solve what the abstract class does, you will need to have the view in every activity